# StorybookConfig not working after reading MUI 5 migration docs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, storybook

I've been researching this for a couple of days and can't find a solution that works for my use case (or at least hasn't worked yet). I am trying to get story book to work with MUI 5 styling. I tried following the migration docs here but still do not see MUI 5 styling appearing in storybook, specifically the global font that I use. I've seen that it has something to do with emotion not being compatible with storybook and have tried using emotion ^11.0.0.

Currently using storybook 6.5 and MUI 5. Any guidance would be massively appreciated.

Here is my preview js:

```
import React from 'react';
/* import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'; */
import { Theme, default as MaterialTheme } from '../src/ui/GlobalTheme';
import { ThemeProvider as Emotion10ThemeProvider } from '@emotion/react';

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
};

const withThemeProvider = (Story, context) => {
  return (
    <Emotion10ThemeProvider theme={Theme}>
      <MaterialTheme theme={Theme}>
        <Story {...context} />
      </MaterialTheme>
    </Emotion10ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export const decorators = [withThemeProvider];
```

main.js

```
const path = require('path');
const toPath = (filePath) => path.join(process.cwd(), filePath);

module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx|mdx)'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-links', '@storybook/addon-essentials', '@storybook/addon-storysource'],
  core: {
    builder: 'webpack5',
  },
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    return {
      ...config,
      resolve: {
        ...config.resolve,
        alias: {
          ...config.resolve.alias,
          '@emotion/core': toPath('node_modules/@emotion/react'),
          'emotion-theming': toPath('node_modules/@emotion/react'),
        },
      },
    };
  },
};
```

globaltheme.tsx

```
import {
  ThemeProvider,
  Theme,
  StyledEngineProvider,
  createTheme,
  adaptV4Theme,
} from '@mui/material';
import React from 'react';

export const Theme = createTheme(adaptV4Theme(baseTheme));

const MaterialTheme: React.FC = ({ children }) => (
  <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
    <ThemeProvider theme={Theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>
  </StyledEngineProvider>
);

export default MaterialTheme;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I took your code to test here and I just had to change it no preview.js

```
import { Theme, default as MaterialTheme } from '../src/ui/GlobalTheme';
```

to

```
import { Theme } from '../src/ui/GlobalTheme';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles'


const withThemeProvider = (Story, context) => {
  return (
    <Emotion10ThemeProvider theme={Theme}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={Theme}>
        <Story {...context} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Emotion10ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

sorry for the spelling mistakes, i used google translate